# The limit of the operator norm in a Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, limits-and-convergence

I am not familiar with functional analysis. Could you tell me please, how to prove the following statement (if it is true)?
$$
\lim_\limits{M \to \infty} \|T_A - T_b \| = 0,
$$
here operator norm defined as $\|A\| = \sup_\limits{\| x \| = 1}\| Ax \|$, $x \in \ell^2$. $T_A$ and $T_B$ are operators defined as
$$
T_A = \exp\{\alpha B\},
$$
$$
T_B = \left(E - \frac{\alpha}{M}B \right)^{-(M - p)},
$$
here $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $M \in \mathbb{N}$, $p \in \mathbb{N}$ , and $B$ is the following linear operator
$$
B = \sum_{k} |k\rangle \langle k+1|.
$$

Comment: Is $E$ the identity operator?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, Yes E - identity operator.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, Why? I compare this with a similar limit for functions and $\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{a}{n} \right)^{- (n-p)} = e^a$, not $e^{pa}$.

Comment: Oh you're right, never mind.

Comment: This should have the same proof as the scalar calculus identity that you mention since all the operators involved here ($1,B$) commute, so the fact that we're dealing with operators rather than numbers can't really make itself felt.